# SQL multi table query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three relations: Recipes(name, descr), Ingredients(recipeName, num, val) and Steps(recipeName, num, val).  Each recipe will have one or more ingredients, and one or more steps. I am trying to write a query that will list the ingredients and steps for a single recipe.  With this query

```
SELECT Recipes.name, Recipes.descr, Ingredients.num, Ingredients.val, Steps.num, Steps.val
FROM Recipes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredients ON Recipes.id = Ingredients.recipeName  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Steps ON Recipes.id = Steps.recipeName;
```

This query is like a cross product.  So if my ingredients values for some recipe are 1,ing-a and 2,ing-b and steps values are 1,step-c, 2,step-d and 3,step-e, I get (order is Recipe.name, recipe.descr, Ingredients.num, Ingredients.val, Steps.num, Steps.val)

```
name, descr, 1, ing-a, 1, step-c
name, descr, 1, ing-a, 2, step-d
name, descr, 1, ing-a, 3, step-e
name, descr, 2, ing-b, 1, step-c
name, descr, 2, ing-b, 2, step-d
name, descr, 2, ing-b, 3, step-e
```

Is there a query that would return as shown below (recipe vals, then ingredients, then steps)

```
name
descr
1,ing-a
2,ing-b
1,step-c
2,step-d
3,step-e
```

Comment: You want them in a single column as different rows ??

Comment: You should run three queries.

Comment: how can you have string columns and integer columns in the same column... what do you want exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
DROP TABLE iF EXISTS Recipes;
DROP TABLE iF EXISTS Ingredients;
DROP TABLE iF EXISTS Steps;

CREATE TABLE Recipes
(id INT,
 name VARCHAR(100),
 descr VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Ingredients
(recipeName INT,
 num INT,
 val VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE Steps
(recipeName INT,
 num INT,
 val VARCHAR(100)); 

INSERT INTO  Recipes VALUES (1, 'name', 'descr');

INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES (1, 1, 'ing-a');
INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES (1, 2, 'ing-b');
INSERT INTO Ingredients VALUES (1, 3, 'ing-c');

INSERT INTO Steps VALUES (1, 1, 'step-a');
INSERT INTO Steps VALUES (1, 2, 'step-b');
INSERT INTO Steps VALUES (1, 3, 'step-c');
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT v1.display
  FROM (    SELECT Recipes.id AS sort_key, 1 AS seq, Recipes.name AS display
              FROM Recipes
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Recipes.id AS sort_key, 2 AS seq, Recipes.descr AS display
              FROM Recipes
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Ingredients.recipeName AS sort_key, 3 AS seq, CONCAT(Ingredients.num , ',' , Ingredients.val) AS display
              FROM Ingredients 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Steps.recipeName AS sort_key, 4 AS seq, CONCAT(Steps.num , ',' , Steps.val) AS display
              FROM Steps ) v1
 ORDER BY v1.sort_key, v1.seq, v1.display;
```

**Output**

```
***display***
name
descr
1,ing-a
2,ing-b
3,ing-c
1,step-a
2,step-b
3,step-c
```

Comment: Very nice, I was going to re-write like this.  You don't need the joins -- you can do it without them.

Comment: Thanks @Hogan. Yes, you are right. I have edited to exclude the joins :)

Comment: One follow-up.  Suppose we wanted to lookup one recipe.  How do you modify the query, for example, to return the information for Recipe.id = 2?

Comment: In order for the query to be performant, the condition has to be added to each of the SELECT in the sub-query.

Comment: Thanks.  I was up late last night and figured that out.  I'm very new to SQL, and you were very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to mark the answer as accepted if you are happy with it. See here for instructions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: One more question on your solution.  My recipe steps are sorting 1,10, 11, 12, 2, 3 ...  Wondering how to sort them numerically, so 1,2,3,4,5 ... 11, 12

Comment: It appears the steps are stored as alpha numeric. You just have to convert to a numeric in the order by. For example ORDER BY CONVERT(step_number,UNSIGNED INTEGER)

Answer (score 0):

**I just saw the question changed**  The following might not be valid.

You can use group concat to do this, like this:

```
SELECT
  Recipes.name, Recipes.descr,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Ingredients.num,' ',Ingredients.val) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Ingredients,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Steps.num,' ',Steps.val) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Steps
FROM Recipes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ingredients ON Recipes.id = Ingredients.recipeName  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Steps ON Recipes.id = Steps.recipeName;
GROUP BY Recipes.name, Recipes.descr
```